# Windows won't recognize Microsoft Comfort Curve keyboard

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

I bought a [Microsoft Comfort Curve 3000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/comfort-curve-keyboard-3000) keyboard today.

When I plug it into my PC, Windows shows it can't find the drive, and it won't recognize a single key.

However, I can use this keyboard in the BIOS setup screen and on other PCs.
Before that I used a [Logitech MK250](http://www.logitech.com/en-in/keyboards/keyboard-mice-combos/devices/5844), it's a wireless USB suite.

**EDIT:**
I use windows 7 x64

**UPDATE:**
I have tested another USB Keyboard,it's also failed.Maybe my Windows cannot install USB keyboard drivers?

Comment: Which Windows exactly? Might help.

Comment: Can't find the driver?  Do you have an internet connection when you plug it in?  How about checking device manager and the event log?

Comment: @Paul It seems that there is no driver for this product,even on Microsoft website,and the package of this keyboard.

Comment: do said keyboard show up in device manager? I believe they should work with a generic keyboard driver, which should already be there. If you still have issues, try sfc /scannow to make sure the drivers that should be there, are there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It do shows up,but not as a keyboard.It also displayed the module of my keyboard,but nothing else special.`sfc /scannow` could not find anything.

Comment: curious. could you check if kbdhid.sys and kbdclass.sys are present in C:\Windows\System32\drivers ?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes.I can find them.

Comment: curious. that means the generic drivers for them are in place, yet it dosen't work. Could you check on another system and device manager what drivers they use, and possibly try replacing the drivers with the ones from there?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I replaced those 2 files,but nothing happens.

Comment: I think it might be an issue with .inf files.  Could you go to ```c:\windows\system32\driverstore``` and rename ```infcache.1```

Comment: @Paul I renamed infcache.1,reboot my computer and plug my keyboard,but still cannot find driver.

Comment: Ok... perhaps the original inf and pnf files are corrupted somehow.  You could try coping the keyboard.inf and .pnf and the usb.inf and .pnf files from a machine that works.  But this is just guesswork.  Perhaps try running a Windows 7 repair - not that it really does very much anymore - but you might be able to revert to a restore point that pre-dates the problem.